# Opensearch integration tests with Jest

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using Elasticsearch (Opensearch) in a Nx monorepo in a node js Serverless app that connects to aws services. I would like to use jest to test but so far I have not been able to get responses from Opensearch.

I have in my test file this:

**const { Client } = require("@opensearch-project/opensearch")**

**export const client = new Client({ node: "https://myaws.awszone.amazonaws.com})**

And my test as:

**const data = await client.search(params)**

**expect(data.id).not.toBeNull()**

but get error:

**Async callback was not invoked within the 50000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:**

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add port explicitly to the url `"https://myaws.awszone.amazonaws.com:443"` it might be looking for 9200 by default

Comment: Thanks I will try this